# Packaging Sencha Touch 2.1.1 for Android with Phonegap or Cordova 2.6.0

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2.1

I have been trying to make this happen for a solid day now. All of the tutorials I can find seem to be related to older versions or are incomplete. I've followed instructions to what I can find, but no matter what I can't get the package to work. My latest issue is that when I create a project with cordova it generates a blank AndroidManifest.xml file as well as blank config.xml, strings.xml, and another one I forget off the top of my head. I didn't want to use Phonegap to begin with but if you have external links in Sencha using the native packager it won't open those in a browser. Those links get opened inapp, and you can't get back to your previous view.

How can I overcome this limitation in sencha or how can I integrate Sencha 2.1.1 and Cordova/Phonegap 2.6.0 (or any version really) with Android?

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version of ST2.1.1 there is no way to have external links open in the device browser without using PhoneGap. I ran into exactly the same issue and had to use PhoneGap + the InAppBrowser plugin (which is now part of the core since 2.3.0).